# Kubernetes cluster permissions for watching deployments not picking up events

Tags: go, kubernetes

I have the following config

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: deploy-agent-rbac
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: deploy-agent
    namespace: ais-service
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: deploy-agent
  annotations:
    eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn: arn:aws:iam::<ACCOUNT_ID>:role/pod-identity-role
```

I'm using the Golang Kubernetes API to watch for events, like so:

```
watch, err := k.client.CoreV1().Pods(namespace).Watch(metav1.ListOptions{
    LabelSelector: fmt.Sprintf("service=%s", target),
})
```

However when I update/delete pods in that namespace, with the correct given label, it doesn't show any events. However when I run the same code locally, it does. I suspect the role used for my local environment how the correct permissions, but the namespace I'm running my service in doesn't.

When I run `$ kubectl auth can-i watch deployments --namespace default --as cluster-admin`, I get "no".

Answer (score 1):

The `ClusterRoleBinding` refers to a serviceaccount in `ais-service` namespace but the serviceaccount does not have a namespace which means the service account is created in `default` namespace. Add namespace in serviceaccount

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: deploy-agent
  namespace: ais-service
  annotations:
    eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn: arn:aws:iam::<ACCOUNT_ID>:role/pod-identity-role
```

To verify the permission run below command

```
kubectl auth can-i list deployments --as=system:serviceaccount:ais-service:deploy-agent -n ais-service
```